# Unable to save multiple selections in select lists in a razor page form

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Here I am able to bind the multi-select select list.  And when I attempt to save I do not get an error but it does not save the officer information.

[image: Multi-select binding]

And here is the error while trying to load the page

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   SqlException: Invalid column name 'OfficerID'.
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.b__164_0(Task
>   result)
>
> Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing SqlException: Invalid column name
>   'OfficerID'.
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.b__164_0(Task
>   result)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask.InnerInvoke()
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task+<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0(object obj)
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, object state)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref Task
>   currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject
>   parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject
>   parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject
>   parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable+AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext
>   _, bool result, CancellationToken cancellationToken) Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync(TState state, Func> operation, Func>> verifySucceeded, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable+AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync(IQueryable
>   source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync(IQueryable
>   source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   SecurityCore.PaginatedList.CreateAsync(IQueryable source, int
>   pageIndex, int pageSize) in PaginatedList.cs
>   +
>               var items = await source.Skip( SecurityCore.Pages.SecurityLogs.IndexModel.OnGetAsync(string
>   sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, Nullable
>   pageIndex, string entitySelect) in Index.cshtml.cs
>   +
>               SecurityLog = await PaginatedList.CreateAsync(sort
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory+NonGenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(object
>   receiver, object[] arguments)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(ref
>   State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker
>   invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
>   isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State
>   next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
>   invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
>   isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker
>   invoker)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
>   endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)

**Here is my code...**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SecurityCore.Models;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace SecurityCore.Pages.SecurityLogs
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SecurityCore.Models.SecurityCoreContext _context;

        public IndexModel(SecurityCore.Models.SecurityCoreContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


        public string EventDateSort { get; set; }
        public string EventStartSort { get; set; }
        public string EventEndSort { get; set; }
        public string ContactNameSort { get; set; }
        public string EventTypeSort { get; set; }
        public string ShiftRangeSort { get; set; }
        public string EntitySort { get; set; }
        public string LocationSort { get; set; }
        public string NarrativeSort { get; set; }
        public string OfficerNameSort { get; set; }
        public string FullNameSort { get; set; }            
        public string SubjectDOBSort { get; set; }
        public string RecordLockedSort { get; set; }
        public string CurrentFilter { get; set; }
        public string CurrentSort { get; set; }
        public string IDSort { get; set; }

        public Nullable<DateTime> dateEnd { get; set; }      
        public Nullable<DateTime> dateBegin { get; set; }


        [TempData]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public bool ShowMessage => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Message);
        public PaginatedList<SecurityLog> SecurityLog { get; set; }            


        public async Task OnGetAsync(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? pageIndex, string entitySelect)
        {

            ViewData["EntityID"] = new SelectList(_context.Entity.Where(a => a.Active == "Y"), "ID", "Name");

            CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            IDSort = sortOrder == "ID" ? "ID_Desc" : "ID";
            EventDateSort = sortOrder == "EventDate" ? "EventDate_Desc" : "EventDate";                
            ContactNameSort = sortOrder == "ContactName" ? "ContactName_Desc" : "ContactName";
            EventTypeSort = sortOrder == "EventType" ? "EventType_Desc" : "EventType";
            ShiftRangeSort = sortOrder == "ShiftRange" ? "ShiftRange_Desc" : "ShiftRange";
            EntitySort = sortOrder == "Entity" ? "Entity_Desc" : "Entity";
            LocationSort = sortOrder == "Location" ? "Location_Desc" : "Location";
            NarrativeSort = sortOrder == "Narrative" ? "Narrative_Desc" : "Narrative";
            FullNameSort = sortOrder == "FullName" ? "FullName_Desc" : "FullName";                
            RecordLockedSort = sortOrder == "Locked" ? "NotLocked" : "Locked";
            OfficerNameSort = sortOrder == "OfficerName" ? "OfficerName_Desc" : "OfficerName";

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                pageIndex = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            CurrentFilter = searchString;


            IQueryable<SecurityCore.Models.SecurityLog> sort = from s in _context.SecurityLog select s;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                sort = sort.Where(s =>    s.Narrative.Contains(searchString)                                                                             
                                       || s.RecordLocked.Contains(searchString)
                                       || s.EventDate.ToString().Contains(searchString)                                                                                  
                                       || s.ContactName.Contains(searchString)
                                       || s.Entity.Name.Contains(searchString)
                                       || s.Location.Name.Contains(searchString)
                                       || s.EventType.Name.Contains(searchString)
                                       || s.ShiftRange.Name.Contains(searchString)
                                       || s.ID.ToString().Contains(searchString)
                                       || s.SubjectFirst.Contains(searchString)
                                       || s.SubjectLast.Contains(searchString)
                                       || s.Officer.FullName.Contains(searchString)                                           
                );
            }

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "ID_Desc":
                    sort = sort.OrderByDescending(s => s.ID);
                    break;
                case "ID":
                    sort = sort.OrderBy(s => s.ID);
                    break;
                case "EventDate":
                    sort = sort.OrderBy(s => s.EventDate);                    
                    break;                
                case "ContactName":
                    sort = sort.OrderBy(s => s.ContactName).ThenBy(s => s.EventDate);
                    break;
                case "ContactName_Desc":
                    sort = sort.OrderByDescending(s => s.ContactName).ThenBy(s => s.EventDate);
                    break;
                case "ShiftRange":
                    sort = sort.OrderBy(s => s.ShiftRange.Name).ThenBy(s => s.EventDate);
                    break;
                case "ShiftRange_Desc":
                    sort = sort.OrderByDescending(s => s.ShiftRange.Name).ThenBy(s => s.EventDate);
                    break;
                case "EventType":
                    sort = sort.OrderBy(s => s.EventType.Name).ThenBy(s => s.EventDate);
                    break;
                case "EventType_Desc":
                    sort = sort.OrderByDescending(s => s.EventType.Name).ThenBy(s => s.EventDate);
                    break;
                case "Entity":
                    sort = sort.OrderBy(s => s.Entity.Name).ThenBy(s => s.EventDate);
                    break;
                case "Entity_Desc":
                    sort = sort.OrderByDescending(s => s.Entity.Name).ThenBy(s => s.EventDate);
                    break;
                case "Location":
                    sort = sort.OrderBy(s => s.Location.Name).ThenBy(s => s.EventDate);
                    break;
                case "Location_Desc":
                    sort = sort.OrderByDescending(s => s.Location.Name).ThenBy(s => s.EventDate);
                    break;
                case "Narrative":
                    sort = sort.OrderBy(s => s.Narrative).ThenBy(s => s.EventDate);
                    break;
                case "Narrative_Desc":
                    sort = sort.OrderByDescending(s => s.Narrative).ThenBy(s => s.EventDate);
                    break;                                    
                case "NotLocked":
                    sort = sort.OrderBy(s => s.RecordLocked).ThenBy(s => s.EventDate);
                    break;
                case "Locked":
                    sort = sort.OrderByDescending(s => s.RecordLocked).ThenBy(s => s.EventDate);
                    break;
                case "OfficerName":
                    sort = sort.OrderBy(s => s.Officer.FullName).ThenBy(s => s.EventDate);
                    break;
                case "OfficerName_Desc":
                    sort = sort.OrderByDescending(s => s.Officer.FullName).ThenBy(s => s.EventDate);
                    break;
                default:
                    sort = sort.OrderByDescending(s => s.EventDate);
                    break;
            }

            int pageSize = 12;

            SecurityLog = await PaginatedList<SecurityLog>.CreateAsync(sort
                .Include(a => a.Entity)
                .Include(b => b.EventType)
                .Include(c => c.Location)
                .Include(d => d.ShiftRange)
                .Include(e => e.Officer)
                .Include(f => f.SecurityLogOfficer)                    
                .AsNoTracking(), pageIndex ?? 1, pageSize);           

        }       

    }
}


//The Security Log Model

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;
using ExpressiveAnnotations.Attributes;

namespace SecurityCore.Models
{   
    public class SecurityLog
    {        
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Event Date")]           
        public System.DateTime EventDate { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Shift Range")]       
        //[ForeignKey("ShiftRange")]
        public Nullable<int> ShiftRangeID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        //[ForeignKey("EventType")]
        [Display(Name = "Event Type")]
        public Nullable<int> EventTypeID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Event Start")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy  hh:mm}")]
        public System.DateTime EventStart { get; set; }            

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Event End")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]        
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy  hh:mm}")]
        public System.DateTime EventEnd { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Reporting Person")]
        public string ContactName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        //[ForeignKey("Entity")]
        [Display(Name = "Entity")]
        public Nullable<int> EntityID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        //[ForeignKey("Location")]
        [Display(Name = "Location")]
        public Nullable<int> LocationID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Narrative { get; set; }

        //Set length of narrative displayed
        private int NarrativeLimit = 200;
        [Display(Name = "Narrative")]
        public string NarrativeTrimmed
        {
            get
            {
                if (Narrative.Length > this.NarrativeLimit)
                    return this.Narrative.Substring(0, this.NarrativeLimit) + "...";
                else
                    return this.Narrative;
            }
        }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Subject's First Name")]
        public string SubjectFirst { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Subject's Last Name")]
        public string SubjectLast { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Subject's Name")]
        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return SubjectFirst + " " + SubjectLast;
            }            
        }

        [Display(Name = "Subject's B#/DOB")]
        public string SubjectDOB { get; set; }

        private string _RecordLocked;

        [Display(Name = "Record Locked?")]
        public string RecordLocked 
        {
            get { return _RecordLocked; }
            set
            {
                _RecordLocked = value;
                if (_RecordLocked == "Y")
                {
                    try { 
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }        
        }


        [Display(Name = "Entered By")]
        public string EnteredBy { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Create Date")]
        [ReadOnly(true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreateDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Modified Date")]        
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedDate { get; set; }                

        [Display(Name = "Modified By")]
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="Number of Extinguishers")]        
        public Nullable<int> ExtinguisherNo { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="Total Blankets")]
        public Nullable<int> BlanketNo { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="Cause of Alarm")]
        public string FireAlarmCause { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="Doors Closed in Area?")]
        public string DoorsClosed { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="Number of Staff Responding")]
        public Nullable<int> StaffNo { get; set; }

        public virtual Entity Entity { get; set; }
        public virtual ShiftRange ShiftRange { get; set; }
        public virtual EventType EventType { get; set; }
        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
        public virtual Officer Officer { get; set; }
        public virtual SecurityLogOfficer SecurityLogOfficer { get; set; }        

    }


}

//The Officer Model

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SecurityCore.Models
{
    public class Officer
    {
        [Required]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        //[Required]
        [Display(Name = "Officer's First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        //[Required]
        [Display(Name = "Officer's Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Officer's Name")]
        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return FirstName + " " + LastName;
            }
        }

        [Required]
        public string Active { get; set; }            
        public string LoginName { get; set; }     
        public virtual SecurityLogOfficer SecurityLogOfficer { get; set; }

    }
}

//The SecurityLogOfficer Model

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SecurityCore.Models
{
    public class SecurityLogOfficer
    {
        [Required]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int SecurityLogID { get; set; }

        public int OfficerID { get; set; }                 
    }
}



//The Create Page that I am trying to post from…

using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using SecurityCore.Models;

namespace SecurityCore.Pages.SecurityLogs
{
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SecurityCore.Models.SecurityCoreContext _context;

        public CreateModel(SecurityCore.Models.SecurityCoreContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGetAsync()
        {              
            ViewData["EntityID"] = new SelectList(_context.Entity.Where(a=>a.Active == "Y"), "ID", "Name");
            ViewData["ShiftRangeID"] = new SelectList(_context.ShiftRange.Where(a=>a.Active == "Y"), "ID", "Name");
            ViewData["LocationID"] = new SelectList(_context.Location.Where(a=>a.Active == "Y"), "ID", "Name");
            ViewData["EventTypeID"] = new SelectList(_context.EventType.Where(a=>a.Active == "Y"), "ID","Name");
            ViewData["Officer"] = new SelectList(_context.Officer.Where(a => a.Active == "Y"), "ID", "FullName");

            return Page();
        }

        [TempData]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public SecurityLog SecurityLog { get; set; }

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public int entity { get; set; }
        public int eventType { get; set; }


        SelectList FilteredLocation;
        SelectList FilteredEventType;

        public JsonResult OnGetLocations()
        {


            FilteredLocation = new SelectList(_context.Location.Where(c => c.EntityID == entity).Where(c =>c.Active == "Y").OrderBy(c =>c.Name), "ID", "Name");

            return new JsonResult(FilteredLocation);


        }

        public JsonResult OnGetEventTypes()
        {


            FilteredEventType = new SelectList(_context.EventType.Where(c => c.EntityID == entity).Where(c => c.Active == "Y").OrderBy(c => c.Name), "ID", "Name");

            return new JsonResult(FilteredEventType);     

        }               


        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            ModelState.Remove("EnteredBy");
            ModelState.Remove("ModifiedDate");
            ModelState.Remove("CreateDate");
            ModelState.Remove("ModifiedBy");
            ModelState.Remove("RecordLocked");


            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            SecurityLog.EnteredBy = User.Identity.Name;
            SecurityLog.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
            SecurityLog.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
            SecurityLog.ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name;
            SecurityLog.RecordLocked = "N";

            _context.SecurityLog.Add(SecurityLog);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            Message = "Entry added successfully!";

            return RedirectToPage("Index");

        }



    }
}
```

**And here is my database schema and sample results**

[image: Sql Database Schema]

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: You have a missing column "Invalid column name 'OfficerID'", pleas fix it at first.

Comment: I do have this column in the SecurityLogOfficer table and also in the SecurityLogOfficer Model.  Is it needed elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

As per the error description, Officer table only has ID column. It doesnt have OfficerID Column. Try changing the code to reflect the ID column.

Comment: I'm confused.  The property, OfficerID, is only declared in SecurityLogOfficer.cs.  In the SecurityLog\Index page, I am referencing the FullName property from Officer.cs.  This is being accessed via the public virtual Officer get; set; property.

Comment: Update - If I add the column, 'OfficerID' to the SecurityLog table, which I don't want to do... the error message goes away the securitylog index page adds two distinct rows for the same event because there are 2 security officers assigned to the event.  How could I get the security officers to show in one column with a list of comma concatenated officers?

Comment: The biggest problem I'm having is that I am trying to post values and there's no direct field to bind to in my model.  I have seen some posts that handle this with MVC but have not seen any examples without controllers, actions and views.  How can I do this with just asp.net web application razor pages?